# Page Number in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

Here is a Django template.

```
{% for balance in balances %}

    {{ balance.amount }}

{% endfor %}


{% for price in price %}

    {{ price.amount}}

{% endfor %}
```

I would like to show multiple values in Django template like one after another. I also need to print the page number.

For example, 1,2,3,4 page for balance and 5,6,7 is used for the price.

So is there any way I can print it?

Comment: Can you share your `views.py` and `models.py`?

Comment: as a matter of a quickfix, try to generate a list in your views.py and then iterate thru it with templates filters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/
doable, it is surely doable

Answer (score 0):

For the first request, explain yourself better.

For paging of one or more lists of objects there is already a Class Based View that allows it. The following documentation explains everything clearly:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/pagination/